# Passing method through a directive to a parent directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**edit: Modified the code as per stevuu's suggestion as well as added a plunkr to [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ClRiiERU9htORfn32fyv?p=preview)**

I'm currently attempting to have a child directive call a method(resolve) through another directive all the way up to a parent directive but I'm having difficulties identifying the problem with my approach.

The problem right now seems to be that although resolve() does get called as expected on click, selected remains undefined.

the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Angular: directive using &amp; - jsFiddle demo</title>     
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style type='text/css'>        
  </style>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div grand-parent>
    <span>selected: {{text}}</span>
    <div parent resolve="resolve"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('grandParent', function() {
return {
    scope:{
        resolve: "&"
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.resolve = function(selected){
            $scope.text = selected
            }
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('parent', function(){
    return{
        scope: {
            resolve: "&"
        },
        template: "<div child resolve='resolve'></div>"
    };
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            resolve: "&"
        },
        template: "<div>Click me!</div>",
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            $element.on("click", function(){
                $scope.$apply(function(){
                    $scope.resolve({selected: "Yahoo!!"});
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: To start off, you're not putting `resolve` on `$scope` in `grandParent`! Should read something like `$scope.resolve = ...`.

Comment: Do your directives need to use isolate scopes?  If not, then any method defined on the grandParent's scope will be available to all of the other directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolve: "&" is a mapping. So here:

```
myApp.directive('grandParent', function() {
return {
    scope:{
        resolve: "&"
    },
    link: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.resolve = function(selected){
            $scope.text = selected
            }
        }
    };
});
```

you are trying to map "resolve" to ... nothing, because "grandParent" doesn't have any attr named "resolve".

If you want to share some staff betweens directives you should do something like that:

**view**

```
<div data-grand-parent resolve="resolved()">
    <div data-parent  ></div>
</div>
```

**Directives**

```
var app = angular.module('test');

app.directive('grandParent', function() {
    return {
        scope : {
            resolve : "&" // in view we defined resolve attr
                          // with "resolve()" value, so now resolve=resolved()
                          // in grandParent scope too.
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            this.getResolve = function(){
                return $scope.resolve;
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('parent', function() {
    return { 
        require: "^grandParent", 
        link: function(scope, element, attr, grandParentCtrl){
            grandParentCtrl.getResolve()();
        },
        template : ""
    };
});
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('desktop')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, mocks) {

    $scope.resolved = function(){
        console.log("calling $scope.resolved() ...");
    };

  });
```

**output**

```
calling $scope.resolved() ...
```

So, how does it work?
We defined resolved function in our controller, then we sign this function to attr "resolve" in grandParent directive. Thx to `resolve : "&"` we could mapped that resolved() function to "resolve" property in grandParent scope. At the end we inject grandParent to other directives. That's all.

I recommend you to read angularJs by Brad Green, Shyam Seshadri. it's not the best book but could be worse and it's free. You can find very good tutorial too on http://www.egghead.io/

ps. Sorry for my english ;/